# Scipy.stats / Why can't I get the value for randint?

Tags: scipy

Hello

Here is my code :

```py
from scipy.stats import randint
param_distributions = {'n_estimators': randint(1, 5),
                       'max_depth': randint(5, 10)}
```

*param_distributions["max_depth"]* gives as a result :

> {'n_estimators': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object
> at 0x7f05f1b05210>, 'max_depth':
> <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at
> 0x7f05f1b053d0>}

Why can't I get a value for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randint(low, high)` will return a distribution object. To sample from it, you need to use the `rvs()` method:

```py
from scipy.stats import randint
param_distributions = {'n_estimators': randint(1, 5).rvs(),
                       'max_depth': randint(5, 10).rvs()}
```

```
>>> param_distributions

{'n_estimators': 3, 'max_depth': 9}
```

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html) list all methods available.